# Worklight 6.1, SQL Adapter (Oracle 11g) JNDI error on Tomcat 7.0.42

Tags: oracle11g, tomcat7, ibm-mobilefirst, jndi, worklight-server

We are deploying worklight application on Worklight 6.1, Oracle 11g, and Tomcat 7.0.42.

we are following manual procedure to deploy worklight application on Tomcat 
we configured following files:
Adapter.xml

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">   
         <dataSourceJNDIName>${DataSource-jndi-Local}</dataSourceJNDIName>
    </connectionPolicy>
```

worklight.properties

```
DataSource-jndi-Local = jdbc/WorklightAppDS
```

server.xml(Tomcat 7)

```
<Context path="/App_Name" docBase="App_Name">
        <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightAppDS"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:ORCL"
            username="DBUSER"
            password="DBPASS"/>
        <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightDS"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:ORCL"
            username="DBUSERWORKLIGHT"
            password="DBUSERWORKLIGHTPASS"/>    
        <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:ORCL"
            username="DBUSERWORKLIGHTREPORTS"
            password="DBUSERWORKLIGHTREPORTSPASS"/>

         <Manager pathname="" />
    </Context>
```

after doing the above configuration, Worklight application was deployed and we were able to access worklight console
on context "/App_Name/console".
we deployed .wlapp and .wladapter on the worklight console and when we invoke worklight adapter through application
it says "Runtime: Datasource jdbc/WorklightAppDS not found in jndi".

we tried another two approaches to configure datasource:

1. Added datasource configuration in `<GlobalNamingResources>` tag in server.xml:

   ```
           <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                     type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                     description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                     factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                     pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

           <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightAppDS"
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:ORCL"
               username="DBUSER"
               password="DBPASS"/> 
       </GlobalNamingResources>
   ```
2. Added datasource configuration in context.xml file :

   WEB-INF/web.xml

   ```
           <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightAppDS"
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:ORCL"
               username="DBUSER"
               password="DBPASS"/>

           <!--
           <Manager pathname="" />
           -->
       </Context>
   ```

In these two approaches we are facing same error. i.e. "Runtime: Datasource jdbc/WorklightAppDS not found in jndi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with java:comp/env/${DataSource-jndi-Local} in dataSourceJNDIName.